# why doesn't flow understand my branched return value

Tags: flowtype

Let's take this example:

```
type Obj = {
  number: number,
  string: string,
}

const obj: Obj = {
    number: 1,
    string: "test",
};

type Key = $Keys<Obj>;

const getValue = (key: Key) => {
    return obj[key];
};

const myString = getValue('string');
```

This will return that `myString` is `string | number`.

Since `Flow` knows my `'string'` is one of the possible `key`s, it allows me to get it from obj. Why doesn't it know this can only return a string type?

Answer (score 1):

Doing this wasn't possible in Flow until recently, but you're in luck! The latest 0.49 release comes with an $ElementType utility type that is able to address this.

Here's the [flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDGYCuAtvAKYBOAXDAIwA02M0pAlmAOaUBEUx0HmAvpkwAzPGGBQm4GK2JQAagEMANnmIAeANLEAnpUYtWAPgAUAa12VtOgJSUAJAFFlxAsTBQAKjoAOGqL7EIMJwSDQw1kYY9KRyeKRgoYgA2hY6ALoA3AJCoJCwAB6U+ERkqDJySqrEJgDkJSSktTaYedAwegxQzGzlsgoqanUGbM1CAPTjMGSkIKQQMCTKIADumJMwbbCK+t2GfZWDNfWEjWMbW4vFp2Vo-VVDtSOszUA) link.

Posting the example here just in case the link breaks:

```
const obj = {
  number: 1,
  string: "test"
}

function getValue<Key: string>(key: Key): $ElementType<typeof obj, Key> {
  return obj[key];
}

const x: number = getValue('number')
const y: string = getValue('string')

// errors below
// const a: string = getValue('number')
// const b: number = getValue('string')
```

I cleaned up your example a little bit -- there's no need to create the 'Obj' type, you can just use `typeof`. Hope this helps!

Do note that if you try to use `$Keys<typeof obj>` as your bounds for the generic parameter of `getValue`, $ElementType currently bugs out. That issue is being tracked here: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4211.

Answer (score 0):

Because flow is figuring out your types statically at the **function boundaries only** and **won't run** your code.

Here is your example a little simplified:

```
function foo(x: 'a' | 'b') {
  if (x === 'a') {
    return 'a';
  }
  return 'b';
}
```

You might think we can write:

```
const surprise: 'a' = foo('a');
```

**This is an error** because the return type of foo is **'a' | 'b'**

Comment: That's exactly my problem :( So there is no way to determine the output? In TypeScript you'd use type guards: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Comment: @LaurensKling You can use type check myString and handle all the cases: https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKygXigbwFBSgOwK4C2cEATgFy6HEkA0WUAzsCQJY4DmFTrHdAvhgwBjAPY4mUEYgrwkqTNmz4ipCgEY6ixszacoAImAQm+-gG5BoSFADSEECigASOyAYAeWQD4LGAGZ4OELALGJQ7BDAAGoAhgA2eBAAFADW9hSuAJTo9CSReCQ4kogA2mkgALoWAsJiEgQgAMo6HI4R0fGJSQDk3Lrdmb4sflBJVhAiIw3NPOwoyKi9LewDOdhJ08tcy4P0APR7o5uzFMrUu3xQEHEM0ApHTVuUKiS72AcPM7rbsxdAA. The same code that does type checking in runtime is doing type refinement in Flow

Comment: @LewisChung but this means i have to refine it every single time I use this function. If the foo function is some generic getter, this will result in a bunch of duplicate checking after the fact. And there's no way to create a function to refine it, because that will return 2 possible types still...

Comment: You're in luck -- if you update to the latest Flow release (0.49), there is support for this via the $ElementType utility type